# Generating XML document with C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to generate an XML document that follows this specifictaion

```
<productName locale="en_GB">Name</productName>
```

but using XMLSeralization I am getting the following

```
<productName locale="en_GB">
<Name>Name</Name>
</productName>
```

My C# code is like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class productName
{
    public productName()
    {

    }

    public string Name;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string locale;
}
```

XmlAttribute is what is required to show the locale in the correct place, but I am unable to figure out how to export the Name field correctly.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is the code to generate the XML

```
public static class XMLSerialize
{
    public static void SerializeToXml<T>(string file, T value)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(file))
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }

    public static T DeserializeFromXML<T>(string file)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(file);
        T result;
        result = (T)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: what method are you using to generate the XML from the class?

Comment: Added the xml serialize code to the question

Comment: is *productName*  root element of your XML?

Comment: No the XML is much larger, this is just one element that has the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of specifying *Name* as element specify it as *text value* by adding **[XmlText]** attribute

```
[XmlText]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

This contains not only a direct answer to your question, but more of a indirect answer of how to solve similar issues like this in the future.

Start the other way around, with your xml, write your xml exactly like you want it and go from there, like this:

```
// assuming data.xml contains the xml as you'd like it
> xsd.exe data.xml             // will generate data.xsd, ie xsd-descriptor
> xsd.exe data.xsd /classes    // will generate data.cs, ie c# classes
> notepad.exe data.cs          // have a look at data.cs with your favorite editor
```

Now just have a look at data.cs, this will contain an enormous amount of attributes and stuff and the namespaces are probably wrong, but at least you know how to solve your particular xml-issue.

The direct answer is to use the [XmlTextAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on the given property, preferably named `Value` since that is the convention I've seen so far.

```
[Serializable]
public class productName {
 public productName() { }

 [XmlText]
 public string Value {get; set;}

 [XmlAttribute]
 public string locale {get; set;}
}
```